# What is the usage of the <header> tag in HTML?

Tags: html

It is not entirely clear to me what the best usage of the `<header>` tag is.
I have had this minor discussion with someone at my internship and he said you would only like to use the `<header>` tag inside an `<article>` tag element. I told him it would not be wrong to use it as the element containing the navigation etc. After talking about this, I am still not sure wether I should use it the way I thought it can be used or the way he tried telling me. On school I also learned that HTML5 is turning to a more semantic way of describing ones document. Is the `<header>` tag not supposed to be a part of that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-header-element).

> The header element represents introductory content for its nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element. A header typically contains a group of introductory or navigational aids.
>
> When the nearest ancestor sectioning content or sectioning root element is the body element, then it applies to the whole page.
>
> The header element can also be used to wrap a section's table of contents, a search form, or any relevant logos.

A **sectioning content** can be `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<nav>` or `<section>` (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#sectioning-content-0)

It **isn't mandator**y to use it on an `<article>` section. Even the examples provided shows that:

```
<header>
 <p>Welcome to...</p>
 <h1>Voidwars!</h1>
</header>
```

Regarding you saying

> I told him it would not be wrong to use it as the element containing the navigation etc

the definition tells us that is absolutely ok to use it for **navigational aids** (aka `<nav>`).

Comment: My question still remains: Is it either correct or incorrect to do it either of those ways?

Comment: Both are correct, you can use it on an `<article>` or a `<nav>`.

Answer (score 2):

> The header element typically contains the headings for a section (an h1-h6 element or hgroup element), along with content such as introductory material or navigational aids for the section.

[Source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/header.html)

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_header.asp

Here it even says that the header tag is new in HTML5.
And it is used in articles.

The example here uses article:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_semantic_elements.asp
But it is possible to use it within other semantic tags like nav

Comment: That is why I have my question. I do not read anywhere it has to be used in the article element exclusive. Besides, would it be wrong to use it outside of an article element? That's not something that is stated on that page.

Comment: It's semantic because you use it instead of <div clas="header"> but I can't find if you can use it anywhere else then <article> so I think it belongs there and should not be used anywhere else